# Debugging C code with gdb

Tags: c, gcc, terminal, gdb

This is a homework assignment, I just want help with gdb, not specific answers.

I have no experience with gdb whatsoever and little terminal experience. I followed a simple example online to debug some code using gdb but in the example gdb pointed out that a problem happened when it ran the code. When I try to mimic the process for this assignment gdb doesn't say anything. I am still somewhat new to C, but I can see problems when I look at the code and gdb isn't saying anything.

Say the file is named test.c, in the terminal I type gcc test.c and it gives me a warning because `printf()` is there but `#include <stdio.h>` is not, which is good because that is supposed to be wrong.

It also produces a.out and if I run it in the terminal with ./a.out nothing happens. The terminal just is ready for my next input with no messages. If I type gdb ./a.out and then run it just tells me the program exited normally.

Can someone point out what I have to do to make gdb point to the errors please?

```
// insertion sort, several errors

int X[10],  // input array
    Y[10],  // workspace array  
    NumInputs,  // length of input array
    NumY = 0;  // current number of 
               // elements in Y

void GetArgs(int AC, char **AV) {
    int I;
    NumInputs = AC - 1;
    for (I = 0; I < NumInputs; I++) X[I] = atoi(AV[I+1]);
}

void ScootOver(int JJ) {
    int K;
    for (K = NumY-1; K > JJ; K++) Y[K] = Y[K-1];
}

void Insert(int NewY) {
    int J;
    if (NumY = 0) { // Y empty so far, 
        // easy case
        Y[0] = NewY;
        return;
    }
    // need to insert just before the first Y
    // element that NewY is less than
    for (J = 0; J < NumY; J++) {
        if (NewY < Y[J]) {
            // shift Y[J], Y[J+1],... rightward 
            // before inserting NewY
            ScootOver(J);
            Y[J] = NewY;
            return;
        }
    }
}

void ProcessData() {
    // insert new Y in the proper place
    // among Y[0],...,Y[NumY-1]
    for (NumY = 0; NumY < NumInputs; NumY++) Insert(X[NumY]);
}

void PrintResults() {
    int I;
    for (I = 0; I < NumInputs; I++) printf("%d\n",Y[I]);
}

int main(int Argc, char ** Argv) {
    GetArgs(Argc,Argv);
    ProcessData();
    PrintResults();
}
```

**Edit**: The code is not mine, it is part of the assignment

Comment: "if I run it in the terminal with ./a.out nothing happens". After reading your code, that's exactly what I'd expect to happen. Try entering "./a.out 3 2 1" and see what happens.

Comment: Try it and see! :) Be sure to put spaces between the numbers. Then try putting different numbers in - but don't put in more than ten numbers.

Comment: I did not know argc and argv[] took the arguments passed to the program... that was one lucky Google search. I always ignored those arguments

Comment: It looks to me like this program is intended to take a list of up to 10 integers entered as command-line arguments, sort them in ascending order, and print the sorted list. It also looks to me like it has a bug.

Comment: Yeah, that is the point, it has a few bugs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different kinds of errors. Some can be detected by programs (the compiler, the OS, the debugger), and some cannot.

The compiler is required (by the C standard) to issue errors if it detects any **constraint violations**. It may issue other errors and warnings when not in *standards compliance mode*. The compiler will give you more error diagnostics if you add the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` options. The compiler may be able to detect even more errors if you enable optimizations (`-O0` through `-O3` set different levels of optimization), but you may want to skip optimizations if you want to single-step in the debugger, because the optimizer will make it harder for the debugger to show you the relevant source-lines (some may be re-ordered, some may be eliminated).

The operating system will detect errors involving traversing bad pointers (usually), or bad arguments to system calls, or (usually) floating-point division by zero.

But anything that doesn't crash the program is a **semantic** error. And these require a human brain to hunt for them.

So, as Brian says, you need to set breakpoints and single-step through the program. And, as jweyrich says, you need to compile the program with `-g` to add debugging symbols.

You can inspect variables with `print` (eg. `print Argc` will tell you how many command-line arguments were on the `run` line). And `display` will add variables to a list that is displayed just before each prompt. If I were debugging through that for-loop in `Insert`, I'd probably do `display J` and `display Y[J]`, `next`, and then hit enter a bunch of times watching the calculation progress.

If your breakpoint is deeply nested, you can get a "stack dump" with `backtrace`.

`next` will take you to the next *statement* (following the semicolon). `step` will take you into function calls and to the first statement of the function. And remember: if you're single-stepping through a function and get to the 'return' statement, use `step` to enter the next function call in the calling statement; use `next` at the return to finish the calling statement (and just execute any remaining function calls in the statement, without prompting). *You may not need to know this bit just yet, but if you do, there you go.*

Comment: +1. I'd also recommend compiling with `-g3 -O0`, so gdb can print filenames, symbols, and source lines. Additionally, I recommend the good habit of always compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` (and `-pedantic` when possible).

Comment: @jweyrich Thank you. I've incorporated *some* of that. [Don't want to overload him. :)]

Comment: @luserdroog: Cool! :-) Pity I cannot upvote more than once. Though I cannot think of a case where increasing the optimisation level would change (or improve) error detection. Can you elaborate on that, or give any references?

Comment: Could you explain step by step how to print Argc please?

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist until the program is being `run`. So do `break main`, `run 2 3 4 5`, and `print Argc` should print 5.

Comment: (gdb) `break main`
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000df9
(gdb) `run 2 3 4 5`
Starting program: /Users/Alex/Documents/UIC/Spring 2013/Machine Organization/MO Assignment 1/a.out 2 3 4 5
Reading symbols for shared libraries +. done

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000100000df9 in main ()
(gdb) `print Argc`
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Comment: @jweyrich I picked that by lurking on comp.lang.c. I believe -O3 does extra code-path analysis so it can remove unused paths.

Comment: @asimes Either invoke gdb with the program (`gdb a.out`), or do `file a.out` at the gdb prompt.

Answer (score 2):

From `gdb`, do `break main`, then `run`.

From there, `next` or `step` until you find where you went wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that made something appear. I'll play with breaks